# Alternatives to FMINCON

Tags: matlab, convex-optimization

Are there any faster and more efficient solvers other than fmincon? I'm using fmincon for a specific problem and I run out of memory for modest sized vector variable. I don't have any supercomputers or cloud computing options at my disposal, either. I know that any alternate solution will still run out of memory but I'm just trying to see where the problem is.

P.S. I don't want a solution that would change the way I'm approaching the actual problem. I know convex optimization is the way to go and I have already done enough work to get up until here.

P.P.S I saw the other question regarding the open source alternatives. That's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for more efficient ones, if someone faced the same problem adn shifted to a better solver.

Comment: How large is your decision variable? e.g., how many elements maximum  do you expect to be inside your vector? Also, which sorts of constraints do you need (linear, bound, nonlinear, or all of them)?

Comment: Are you on 32-bit Windows? Can you run the code on a 64-bit machine with 64-bit Matlab or do you not have either?

Comment: @horchler I do have a 64-bit machine. I have tried on both. They do run out of memory. How does it matter what arch-type the system is?

Comment: But are you running 32-bit Windows and/or 32-bit Matlab on this 64-bit machine? Matlab running in a 32-bit environment -no matter what the actual CPU is- will have access to [at most 2 or 3 GB of memory](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/311072). If you have access to a Mac with Matlab, these are be guaranteed to be fully 64-bit (provided that it's not more than 6-7 years old).

Comment: @horchler No,no, the installation is proper. I just don't have a good pc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm...

Without further information, I'd guess that `fmincon` runs out of memory because it needs the Hessian (which, given that your decision variable is 10^4, will be `10^4 x numel(f(x1,x2,x3,....))` large).

It also takes a lot of time to determine the values of the Hessian, because `fmincon` normally uses finite differences for that if you don't specify derivatives explicitly.

There's a couple of things you can do to speed things up here.

- If you know beforehand that there will be a lot of zeros in your Hessian, you can pass sparsity patterns of the Hessian matrix via `HessPattern`. This saves a lot of memory and computation time.
- If it is fairly easy to come up with explicit formulae for the Hessian of your objective function, create a function that computes the Hessian and pass it on to `fmincon` via the `HessFcn` option in optimset.
- The same holds for the gradients. The `GradConstr` (for your non-linear constraint functions) and/or `GradObj` (for your objective function) apply here.

There's probably a few options I forgot here, that could also help you. Just go through all the options in the optimization toolbox' [optimset](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/optim/ug/optimization-options-reference.html) and see if they could help you.

If all this doesn't help, you'll really have to switch optimizers. Given that `fmincon` is the pride and joy of MATLAB's optimization toolbox, there really isn't anything much better readily available, and you'll have to search elsewhere.

[TOMLAB](http://tomopt.com/tomlab/) is a very good commercial solution for MATLAB. If you don't mind going to C or C++...There's [SNOPT](http://www.sbsi-sol-optimize.com/asp/sol_product_snopt.htm) (which is what TOMLAB/SNOPT is based on). And there's a bunch of things you could try in the GSL (although I haven't seen anything quite as advanced as SNOPT in there...).

I don't know on what version of MATLAB you have, but I know for a fact that in R2009b (and possibly also later), `fmincon` has a few real weaknesses for certain types of problems. I know this ***very well***, because I once lost a very prestigious competition (the [GTOC](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Operations/Global_Trajectory_Optimisation_Competition)) because of it. Our approach turned out to be *exactly the same* as that of the winners, except that they had access to SNOPT which made their few-million variable optimization problem converge in a couple of iterations, whereas `fmincon` could not be brought to converge *at all*, whatever we tried (and trust me, ***WE TRIED***). To this day I still don't know exactly why this happens, but I verified it myself when I had access to SNOPT. Once, when I have an infinite amount of time, I'll find this out and report this to the MathWorks. But until then...I lost a bit of trust in `fmincon` :)

Comment: Alright..thanks. So, find the hessian - that's one way to try and get (coax) a solution out of fmincon. I'm trying to use cvxopt. Let's see how that turns out.

Comment: @SPRajagopal: cvxopt? I don't know that one...please let me know how that works out :)

Comment: Yeah well, didn't go great. I just posted another question regarding an error in that.